# How do parallelize apache-beam (Dataflow) pipeline DAGs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache-beam 2.5.0 python SDK

Attaching the code snippet, in a pipeline, I am taking i/p from pubsub topic parsing it and want to perform some operation on it, when I ran it with DataflowRunner it runs fine but it seems that "data processing fun1", "data processing fun2" "data processing fun3" are running in sequential, I need it to run in parallel.
I am new to dataflow.

Is there a way to parallelize it?

```python
def run():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
   options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

   with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
       data = (p | "Read Pubsub Messages" >> 
            beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=config.pub_sub_topic)
              | "Parse messages " >> beam.Map(parse_pub_sub_message_with_bq_data)
            )

       data | "data processing fun1 " >> beam.ParDo(Fun1())
       data | "data processing fun2" >> beam.ParDo(Fun2())
       data | "data processing fun3" >> beam.ParDo(Fun3())
if __name__ == '__main__':
   run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need these functions to run at the same time?

Beam / Dataflow take your graph, and try to optimize things that can run in the same thread. This called *fusion* optimization, and it's mentioned in the [Flume Java paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35650.pdf).

The point is that it will usually be more efficient to run those functions one by one on the same thread, rather than interchange data between multiple processing threads or VMs, to parallelize the processing.

If your funtions *must* run more or less in parallel, you can add a `beam.Reshuffle` transform before the downstream transforms:

```
data = (p 
        | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic)
        | beam.Map(parse_messages))

# After the data has been shuffled, it may be consumed by multiple workers
data | beam.Reshuffle() | beam.ParDo(Fun1())
data | beam.Reshuffle() | beam.ParDo(Fun2())
data | beam.Reshuffle() | beam.ParDo(Fun3())
```

Let me know if I can add some detail into this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am performing different operations on the same data, Lets suppose fun1 ,fun2 ,fun3 runs one after another and it takes 15 mins  for job completion, i.e. 5 min for each, but i want my job to finish(all three functions to execute) in 5 mins. Although beam.Reshuffle() is working in parallel(checked using stackdriver logs) like you suggested but the performance is same i.e. it takes 15 min to complete all the three function. Can you suggest anything to increase performance?

Comment: So you want the latency for each element to be 5 minutes at most? If you have multiple elements, and multiple workers, your job will parallelize over those multiple elements, so the throughput will be very good, although the latency of an individual element will still be 15 minutes. Is this not good enough?